# Are there logging frameworks or well-known design patterns for Ada in addition to Alog (http://www.nongnu.org/alog/)?

Tags: logging, log4j, ada

Such as something similar to log4j?

Comment: This question was asked nearly 2 1/2 years ago and just popped up in my Ada tag feed. I'm glad to see that I'm not the only one getting these belated notifications :-)  (Unless it was just asked and got tagged with a grossly errant post date?)

Answer (score 1):

This question was recently answered by Thomas Løcke on the [ada-dk](http://ada-dk.org) website.

Excerpt from the news:

> The other day Marc C. posted a link to an AdaCore Gem dealing with the very nice [GNATColl.Traces package](http://www.adacore.com/2011/11/22/gem-114-logging-with-gnatcoll-traces/), and shortly thereafter he did another reddit/r/ada post collecting a bunch of [Ada logging tools](http://www.reddit.com/r/ada/comments/mlhok/logging_options_for_ada/).
>
> As it turns out, there are five very nice solutions available to us Ada'ists:
>
> - [Alog](http://www.codelabs.ch/alog/)
> - [GNATCOLL.Traces](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/gnat-component-collection/)
> - [Log4Ada](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/liblog4ada0)
> - [AWS.Log package in AWS](http://libre.adacore.com/libre/tools/aws/)
> - [IAL.Log package in YAMI4](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/)

See the full post for more details: [Logging options for Ada](http://ada-dk.org/?page=news&news_id=384)

Answer (score 0):

In the Debian repositories there are Log4Ada ([liblog4ada0](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/liblog4ada0)) and Alog ([libalog0.3-full](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/libalog0.3-full)).

Log4Ada seems to be modelled after log4j.